# Is the [repo]-tag needed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

We have three tags with basically the same meaning “repository” out there:

[repository](/questions/tagged/repository) with 1,526 questions tagged
[repositories](/questions/tagged/repositories) with 106 questions tagged
[repo](/questions/tagged/repo) with 144 questions tagged

I'd suggest making the latter both a synonym to [repository](/questions/tagged/repository), especially as repo is an in my opinion bad abbreviation of repository.

What do you think about it?

Comment: I personally think "repo" is a perfectly fine abbreviation for "repository", but as with all abbreviations, it can be confusing for those not familiar with the term to begin with, or those that confuse it with "repro" which is short for "reproduce".

Comment: @cdeszaq - IMO confusing the tag with "reproduce" would only occur on Meta sites.

Comment: @Lix - Yes, it is _much_ more commonly used on Meta with regards to tagging, but the concept is still very much used for any sort of bug finding in programming in general, especially when dealing with bug tracking systems.

Comment: @cdeszaq - you have a valid argument.  However I'm failing to imagine someone needing on any [SE] site (that I know of) to tag a question with a "reproduce" tag.  Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @Lix I agree that such a tag isn't needed on any SE site. I was merely commenting on "repo" as an abbreviation and it's similarity to "repro" as an abbreviation. In particular, pointing out such similarities can be useful when writing the wiki text for a tag to assist in limiting mis-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with first answer, [repo](/questions/tagged/repo) should be related to Google's git-repo tool. I have cleaned up the [repo](/questions/tagged/repo) tag to keep only questions related the  tool, retagging others (mostly related to the general DVCS repository) to [repository](/questions/tagged/repository).

Also [repo](/questions/tagged/repo) has now a tag wiki telling to use it only for questions related to git-repo tool.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm wondering if it'd help to rename that to git-repo as well. Of course, that's not going to stop users from using it to mean "Git repository", but at least it's not as ambiguous.

Comment: What about "repositories"?

Comment: I'd say it should be synomized to "repository", but I don't have enough rep on this tag to suggest it.

Answer (score 3):

It probably ought to stick around for [this](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) [tool](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html):

> Repo is a tool that makes it easier to work with Git in the context of Android

However, I would say that all [repo](/questions/tagged/repo)-tagged questions not related to this tool should be re-tagged [repository](/questions/tagged/repository).